# SlickGrid re-apply/fix filter after sort

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I am building on the tree/expand collapse SlickGrid example found [here](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example5-collapsing.html).

I've added sorting to it(on the % Complete column), but once sorting is triggered by the user the filter does not update - expand/collapse icons don't work and are in the wrong place.

How do I re-apply the filer after the sort? 
I've Tried using the code below but it doesn't work:

```
 dataView.setFilter(myFilter);
 grid.render();
```

You can see a fiddle of what I have [here](http://jsfiddle.net/davidoleary/aKeup/)

**Update** 
I've noticed when I open the jsFiddle page the html section can appear blank, if you refresh the page the code seems to appear.

**Update**
I've managed to create an ugly work around. you can find an updated example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/davidoleary/8mJRR/)

Basically I sort the data an then destroy and recreate the grid. I'd still like to know if there is a more elegant solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're fiddle links don't actually run for my machine, but from reading your source code you either have to rebuild the DataView or you have to force a your DataView to trigger the fitler to recreate all of the indents and collapse/expand elements.

The easiest way to force a refresh is to call `grid.invalidate()` followed by `grid.render()`. If that doesn't work you can call `updateItem()` on each element as it's sorted. Either of these will force the grid to recalculate the row indices and the visual for those indices.

Note you'll have to be careful with sorting, as the parent relationships are not forced upon the row ordering -- aka a child (id 5) of an item (id 2) could be resorted to row 1 above it's parent and collapsing the parent would still make it disappear. It looks like your sorting algorithm handles this already, but it's an important point for anyone else reading the question.